# Two finitely generated abelian groups are isomorphic iff they are embedded in each other

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

**Suppose** $A$ and $B$ are finitely generated abelian groups, $A$ has a subgroup that's isomorphic to $B$ and vice versa. **Then** A is isomorphic to $B$.

My guess (since $A,B$ are finitely generated) is to use *the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups* and somehow trace images of generators.

Comment: Yes, you should use the fundamental theorem. A finitely generated abelian group is completely determined by how many copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ and the groups $\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ occur in a direct sum decomposition of it; just count these.